# Prismic and Ruby on rails : undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to get data from prismic api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prismic.io

I'm quite new to ruby and prismic. 
I'm trying to connect on the controller of  my ruby on rails project to the prismic api.

their tutorial show the following code :

```
api = Prismic.api('https://your-repo-name.prismic.io/api')
doc = api.query(Prismic::Predicates.at("document.type", "page"))
content = doc.results
```

i installed the prismic gem correctly and put my repo name correctly. 
When i run my code, i get the following error :

```
NoMethodError in PageController#page
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

for the line

```
doc = api.query(Prismic::Predicates.at("document.type", "page"))
```

I checked the api variable value and i get #`<Prismic::API:0x007fbcaaab6418>` in my api variable, so i guess it's working fine. 
I tried to change the predicates but it's doesn't change anything.

If you know a way to solve this problem i would be very gratefull. 
Thanks.

**edit:** my controller page where the error occurs :

```
Class PageController < ApplicationController
  def page

    api = Prismic.api('https://xxx.prismic.io/api')
    puts 'api ='
    puts api
    puts '==was api'
    doc = api.query(Prismic::Predicates.at("document.tags", ["conseil"]))
    content = doc.results

    puts 'content'
    @test1 = 'test'#content[0]['id']

  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us your `PageController`, where the error is pointing?